# console.logging numbers starting with 0

Tags: javascript

Just an odd question not sure quite how to ask and cant find the answer to my question so asking here. Sorry this is a strange and dumb question but I was just fooling around typing random code:

```
    var thing=prompt("what number?");
    if(thing<100)
{
    console.log(001001001);
}
    else
{
    console.log(0101001);
}
```

I really made this for no reason and it serves no logical purpose.Its funny because when I type console.log(001001001) the editor I use even says don't use extra leading 0s. Why is it that 001001001 comes out as 262657 and 0101001 prints out 33281 and so on? I'm just curious and I couldn't find this anywhere on google or stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0 prefix means that your integer literals are expressed as octals. Simiarly 0x would mean that the number is hexadecimal. [See more information here.](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/constant.htm)

Comment: What would be an example of needing to use an octal in js?

Comment: @jharclerode: You don't need to use octal in JS or anywhere else for that matter. The same applies to decimal, binary, and hexadecimal. The "leading 0" and "leading 0x" notations come from (AFAIK) C and in C, bit twiddling is often more convenient in octal or hex. Octal is mostly a historic artifact in JavaScript.